# How to increase performance in two way binding in angular directive using isolated scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have a directive 'sim-grab' which would add event handlers for custom events 'pointOver' & 'pointOut' on a set of information tiles. I need to show a visualization on top of the information tile when these events are fired.

The information tiles are populated using ng-repeat. The problem I face is that there is a small delay (little over 700ms) in these visualizations being shown. Please note that 'pointOver/Out' events can be triggered multiple times in a second.

It would be great if someone could advise me if I'm taking a wrong approach in the below code.

Directive:

```
    .directive('simGrab', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : {
            data : "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {

            var _pointOverEvents = 'pointOver';
            var _pointOutEvents = 'pointOut';


            var initialize = function () {
                toggleListeners(true);

            };

            var onPointOver = function(evt) {


                if(scope.data) {

                    if(evt) {
                        //turn on grab visualization
                        scope.data.isGrabbable = true;
                    }
                       //turn on point visualization
                    scope.data.isPointed = true;

                }

            };

            var onPointOut = function(evt) {

                if(scope.data) {

                    //turn off grab visualization
                    scope.data.isPointed = false;
                    scope.data.isGrabbable = false;
                }

            };

            var toggleListeners = function (enable) {
                // remove listeners

                if (!enable){
                    console.log("simGrab destroyed");
                    return;
                }
                // add listeners.
                element.on(_pointOverEvents, onPointOver);
                element.on(_pointOutEvents,onPointOut);
                scope.$on('$destroy', onDestroy);

            };

            var onDestroy = function (enable) {
                toggleListeners(false);
            };

            initialize();
        }
    };
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div class = "feed-box normal" ng-repeat="feed in normEntries" >

<div class="feed-element normal"  ng-class="'color'+($index+1)"  ng-click="setCurrFeed(feed)" sim-grab data="feed">
    <div class="feed-title normal">{{feed.title}}</div>
    <div class="time-ago">{{feed.date}}</div>
    <p  ng-bind-html="feed.summary"></p>
</div>

<div class="tip-container-centered" ng-show="feed.isPointed">
    <div class='open-bar'>
        <div class='open-bar-text'>OPEN</div>
        <div class='open-bar-bg'>
            <span class="text">OPEN</span>
            <span class='open-sphere'></span>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

<div class="tip-container-bottom-right" ng-show="feed.isGrabbable">
    <div class="gesture grab" >GRAB</div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you create a plunkr with problem?

Answer (score 2):

The Problem of repeating much Angular bindings is, that for each binding a watcher exists. If you have to much bindings the page will be slow. If you use Angular 1.3+ you can use {{::feed.title}}. The "::" is [one time binding](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/expression#one-time-binding), you should use where you can to reduce the amount of watchers. If you use a lower angular version you can use https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once . You should always bind things, which will not change, one time.

You can use the chrome Plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-watchers/nlmjblobloedpmkmmckeehnbfalnjnjk to get the count of current watchers.

Also you can use the "track by" notation within the ng-repeat to reduce.

For example if the feed.title doesnt change do something like this:

```
<div class="feed-title normal">{{::feed.title}}</div>
```

Comment: I tried the plugin mentioned and there are 56 watchers reported by the plugin. I think this is not much compared to 555 watchers in some of the other angular based websites such as plunker. However, I tried using scope.$apply() and it solved the problem.